# Insert code inside string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-5, string-interpolation

I'm new to RoR. I'm trying to print the string of the current user name logged in inside the string 'Logout' to personalise the message, but I can only get a print of the code...

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to('Log out #{current_user.first_name}', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: use double quotes for the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes when you have to interpolate

```
<%= link_to("Log out #{current_user.first_name}", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

Comment: (Sure, it's a dupe, but that's not a valid reason to downvote a correct answer.)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm not very familiar with ROR terms yet (string interpolation) to formulate the exact question. +++

Comment: @DaveNewton what was the comment about. I didn't get that

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer, which was improper behavior.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<%= link_to("Log out #{current_user.first_name}", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

you can't use interpolation with single-quoted string. Instead you can use double quotes.